# How to get cell content to the right of n'th special character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

From this cell content in Excel `MB_Dyt01_MB_Dyt11` I need to extract everything right of the second underscore "_" character.

I have tried with this formula

```
=RIGHT(E12;FIND("_";SUBSTITUTE(E12;"_";"_";2))+10)
```

Which returns `yt01_MB_Dyt11` Not correct.

And with this fomula `=RIGHT(E35;FIND("_";E35;4)-1)`

Which returns `03_Fm09`

Can you help me extract the text `MB_Dyt11` from the above cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

```
=MID(A1;FIND("~";SUBSTITUTE(A1;"_";"~";2))+1;999)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add to BigBen's answer, you can use the combination of len() and right() instead of mid() so that the formula would work on text strings of any length

=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","~",2)))